# Can't view "page views" via the Stack Exchange Android app

Tags: feature-request, android-app

The Android application for Stack Exchange doesn't show page views, the time on which it was asked and its state.

Comment: And why is it important to add that?

Comment: I was just thinking the same thing.. Would be useful. Is that info actually in the API though ?

Comment: Why? So that you can determine how old the post is,whether its dead or active and the extent  of attention it caught / how popular it is. That's why!

Comment: What you mean by "state"? It does show when the question is closed. Anyway, please stick with one feature request per question

Comment: I can't see 'page views' as an indicator of post age and its activeness. At best, it only shows if it's popular or not. But that's me...

Comment: Yeah, that is true. I was referring to something other than that. Perhaps reading my post would help you.